# Android RecyclerView ItemTouchHelper control swipe area

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe, itemtouchhelper

So i have a recyclerview, and i'm setting an ItemTouchHelper to perform swipe on the whole itemView. It happens my itemView have items that need to be swiped as well. I managed to get it working by using a special 'swipe layout' that will perform the swipe animation on it.

My problem is that, when i swipe a child view of my recyclerView itemView, the parent is also swiped at the same time. I tried to call

```
requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent
```

on the child view but nothing happens. Is there any way i can limit the parent swipe area (through itemtouchhelper) so that it will only swipe the view if i click at the top half part of the itemView?

Comment: I'm trying to solve almost exactly the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: It is ridiculous how many exactly the same questions are out there, but none has an answer. Goolge should have definitely considered this as a common use case.